# Get some Sort of Identifier Specifying Which Access Point Another Computer is On-On our WAN

Tags: wireless-access-point

Is their someway, knowing the IP address of the machine in question, to somehow determine the Access Point that it was currently connected to?  I see this probably requiring something client side (I'd much prefer not to have to), if not, however, please inform me as to how this can be done.